# Sorting the dates in an array?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

In my application I have an array of strings representing the dates in the Format MM/dd/YYYY

and below is the code I used to sort this array

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter =[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];

[formatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/YYYY"];
NSLog(@" arr %@",arr);
[arr sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2)
 {

     NSDate *date1=[formatter dateFromString:obj1];
     NSDate *date2=[formatter dateFromString:obj2];
     return [date1 compare:date2];
 }];
NSLog(@" arr %@",arr);
```

below is the output of nslog

```
2013-04-08 17:23:48.112 SEEMR[2792:c07]  arr (
    "02/18/2013",
    "02/16/2013",
    "02/14/2013",
    "01/16/2013",
    "02/13/2013",
    "03/16/2013"
)
2013-04-08 17:24:07.662 SEEMR[2792:c07]  arr (
    "02/18/2013",
    "02/16/2013",
    "02/14/2013",
    "01/16/2013",
    "02/13/2013",
    "03/16/2013"
)
```

But it is not sorting as expected so help me peers

Comment: for sorting date your date should be in yyyy/MM/dd format for correct sorting

Comment: [datearray sortUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
with date time format yyyy-MM-dd

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using `NSDateFormatter`, always test if your formatting string is correct. Yours isn't. It should be `MM/dd/yyyy` (the case is important).

In other words, since your formatter works incorrectly, all `dateFromString:` return `nil` and you are always comparing `nil` with a `nil`, which returns `0`.

Saving your dates as a `NSDate` instances would make your life easier. In general, it's better to convert the date into `NSString` only if you are presenting it to the user or sending it to some other application (e.g. web service).

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
NSSortDescriptor* sortByDate = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"date property name" ascending:YES];
[mutableArray sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortByDate]];
```

Hope it helps!